# What is the difference between object vs type as base classes?

Tags: python

I would usually initialize a class this way,

```
class C:
  pass
```

but if I do something like this,

```
class A(object):
  pass
```

and if I do,

```
class B(type):
  pass
```

then, if I run,

```
dir(A)
```

it gives me this list,

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

while

```
dir(B)
```

gives me this list,

```
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__',
 '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__',
 '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__',
 '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
 '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__',
 '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
```

but I can use these on class `A` also, for example, I can use `A.__bases__`, `A.mro`, although it is not listed in `dir(A)`

```
A.mro, A.__bases__
```

gives,

```
(<function A.mro>, (object,))
```

while,

```
B.mro, B.__bases__
```

gives,

```
(<method 'mro' of 'type' objects>, (type,))
```

Furthermore, when I create instances, then,

```
# both have object as base class
a = A() 
c = C()
```

works, but,

```
# type as base class
b = B()
```

gives this error,

```
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

It appears that by default `object` is the base class, but I still am confused when exactly should I specify, `type` as a base class?
And what more differences are there between the two?

Comment: You should not specify `type` as a base class.  `type` would be used to create objects that are types, not objects.  It's a level of metaprogramming that you will probably never need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears that as soon as I specify `type` as the base class, my class becomes a class creator.
so, instances of a class with `type` as the base class, will be classes.
that is,

```
# with type as base class
b = B()
```

would give an error,

```
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

but,

```
b = B('B', (object,), {})
```

would work, and now, `b` itself is a class, and I can create instances of it

```
d = b()
type(d)
```

gives,

```
__main__.B
```

whereas, if I specified,

```
b = B('B', (type,), {})
```

then `b` is again a class creator, and instances of it will be classes themselves.